# Is there a way to access spreadsheet data?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I love new spreadsheet editor. It's good to have it together with geometry nodes, but I think there is one feature missing. I can't export data to external file (I'd like to use it outside Blender). Does anybody know if there is a way to access evaluated instances data via python? I've been trying many things, but the only way for me is to "make instances real" and then access it by looping all objects in the scene, which is not quite what I need. It would be nice to access data visible in the spreadsheet editor window.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the time being there is not way to access data from Spreadsheet editor, but keep an eye on patch [D12546](https://developer.blender.org/D12546) which implements support for exporting to CSV.

Unfortunately I do not know a way to access geometry nodes output

Comment: Hi. Is the export to CSV not available still? Do I need to install the patch as Im not sure how this is done. Thanks!