Is it still not possible to access or copy data from the geometry nodes spreadsheet?
I've seen this question asked many times, and I've seen reference to a patch that would have enabled this functionality, but it was 3 years ago. I can't seem to find anything more on it.

Hello and welcome! Your question looks a lot like a duplicate. But it depends on what exactly you mean by “access or copy data”. I'm guessing you want to do an export. So yes and no, it is partially possible under certain circumstances. Here are the relevant questions/answers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293496/ & https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235465/

Yeah, I've seen both of those (though the second one isn't much of an answer if the csv patch isn't live yet). The first doesn't totally work for my circumstances. Thanks though!

Could you develop why "The first doesn't totally work for my circumstances" ?
